# constructing a nested dictionary using dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Getting frustrated here so help very welcome.

I have a file, data_fields

```
lname,fname,age,UID
macpherson,tom,16,219 
goldman,tim,13,316
smith,jon,11,414
doe,jon,59,512
```

I am making a dictionary keyed on the 'UID' value as below

```
import csv
with open(data_fields) as readme:
    reader = csv.reader(readme)
    headers = reader.next()
    UIDindex = headers.index('UID')
    people = dict()
    for person in reader:
        people[person[UIDindex]] = {k:v for k,v in zip(headers,person) if not k=='UID'}
import pprint
pprint.pprint(people)

{'219': {'age': '16', 'fname': 'tom', 'lname': 'macpherson'},
'316': {'age': '13', 'fname': 'tim', 'lname': 'goldman'},
'414': {'age': '11', 'fname': 'jon', 'lname': 'smith'},
'512': {'age': '59', 'fname': 'jon', 'lname': 'doe'}}
```

Which works OK~ish.
But in the interest of not creating the people dict() up front I've been trying to put some form of dict comprehension together that would include the 'for person in reader loop' and allow me to do

```
return <elusive dict comprehension yielding same dict as above>
```

In this endeavour I have failed, roundly. and have spent a frustrating amount of time on it. Time to ask the experts here!
Can any one help with this elusive comprehension? Is this possible with python (running 2.7.6 here).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that:

```
people={person[UIDindex]:{k:v for k,v in zip(headers, person) if not k=='UID'} for person in reader}
```